# Question regarding the image of a polynomial map containing a small box

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, polynomials

I have the following question, which intuitively seems it should be true but I wasn't sure how to prove it rigorously.

Let $\delta, \varepsilon > 0$. 
Let $\Psi_i(w_1, w_2, \mathbf{v})$ be a polynomial in $n$ variables for $1 \leq i \leq 2$. 
Let us fix $\mathbf{w}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{v}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n-2}$. 
Let $B = \mathbf{w}_0 + [- \delta, \delta]^2$ and $\Psi = (\Psi_1, \Psi_2): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose we have $( \Psi(\mathbf{w}_0, \mathbf{v}_0) + [- 2 \varepsilon, 2 \varepsilon]^2 ) \subseteq \Psi(B, \mathbf{v}_0)$.

I want to prove that there exists $\lambda > 0 $ such that 
given any $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n-2}$ with $\| \mathbf{v} - \mathbf{v}_0 \|_{\infty} < \lambda$,  we have 
$$
( \Psi(\mathbf{w}_0, \mathbf{v}_0) + [-  \varepsilon,  \varepsilon]^2 ) \subseteq \Psi(B, \mathbf{v}). 
$$

As long as the change in $\mathbf{v}$ is small, I would expect the image $\Psi(B, \mathbf{v})$ shouldn't be too different from  $\Psi(B, \mathbf{v}_0)$ so I think this should hold. However, I wasn't sure how to prove this rigorously... I might be missing something very simple here. I would appreciate any comments or suggestions. Thank you very much.